# Installing a blogging platform inside of Github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm using Github pages for my personal portfolio site, and I want to install a blogging platform as well. I've come across jekyll-bootstrap, and it works fine on my local machine. However, is there a way to clone this git project inside a directory such as /blog/ in my Github pages? When I try to do this, I get a page build error.

Comment: A quick google search turned up several results.  Have you tried searching?    e.g.  https://blog.r3bl.me/en/jekyll-blogging-like-a-pro/

Comment: @Matt Yes, I've looked at guides like that. However, no matter what I try, I keep getting build errors from Github. It seems all the guides are meant for creating the blog as the only thing in your Github page, as opposed to it being behind a subdirectory.

Comment: Put your jekyll in a `blog` repository in `gh-pages` branch, set `baseurl: /blog` and add a link to your repo if you want helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you already have a Github page as your portfolio, if I understand correctly you want to keep that and also have a `/blog` alongside with the current pages without mixing both things.

If this is the case, what you could do is copy your jekyll `_site` content (that is already working on your local) into the desired `/blog` directory in your current git that is holding your current Github page (and push the changes to Github).

You don't need to copy all jekyll's files (plugins, posts and so on), jekyll is a generator, so what you publish is the output that is stored at `_site`

please note, you will need to set a baseurl to `/blog` or `/portfoliopages/blog`

hope this helps